# passing file name and specific string in file into for loop using batch file

Tags: batch-file

Here is my another challenge. When I pass the file name into for loop, I want to get a specific word from the file name and need to pass that as a parameter as well.

For eg:
When there are 5 files in a folder say

Encrypted_abc_1.xml
Encrypted_xyz_2.xml
Encrypted_hij_3.xml
Encrypted_klm_4.xml
Encrypted_nop_5.xml

I want to pass the file name Encrypted_abc_1.xml and abc into the for loop. I got the answer for both in seperate for loops however how can i merge into one single for loop

First for loop will fetch the word

```
for /f "tokens=2 delims=_." %%a in (Encrypted_*.xml /b) do (

Echo %%a
```

Another for loop will get the full file name

```
for /R "%Path%" %%f in (Encrypted_*.xml) do (

Echo %%f
```

I want to merge in single for loop. Can you please help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

```
@echo off
setlocal

for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('dir /b %1\Encrypted*.xml') do (
  echo %%a & for /f "tokens=2 delims=_" %%b in ("%%a") do (
    echo %%b
  )
)
```

Make sure you pass in the path to the script.
Here is the output I get

```
C:\temp>testfilenameparse.cmd c:\path
Encrypted_abc_1.xml
abc
Encrypted_samp_3.xml
samp
Encrypted_xyz_2.xml
xyz
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick post Matt.. But nothing came out when i run it.. I have run it below to check all my expected variables are echoing correctly before I move this to my main code, it came out nothing..

Comment: @ECHO OFF
SET Path=%1

SET Path=%Path:"=%
ECHO "%Path%"
setlocal
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('dir /b Encrypted_*.xml') do (

ECHO %%a & for /f "tokens=2 delims=_" %%f in ("%%a") do (
Echo %%a
Echo %%f
ECHO "%Path%\%%f.txt"
ECHO %7
ECHO %6
)

Pause:

Comment: Don't use path as a variable, especially without setlocal. Are you running the script from the directory that contains the Encrypted*.xml files? What does %1 echo out to? How are you running the script?

Comment: %Path is a parameter where the xmls are stored.. I am running my batch script outside of the xmls directory. For example batch file is in C:\batch\abc.bat and xmls are stored in C:\batch\xmls\abd_cde\Encrypted_xyx_1.xml. The path of batch file is constant however the path of xml will be dynamic hence I am passing the path of xml as variable from my vbs file to abc.bat

Comment: path is a reserved environment variable. open a cmd prompt and type `set path` to see what I mean. See revised code.